# Valid to move $x$ to other side of equation in differentials?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Say you have $dy/dx = x$, is it valid to write $dy/x = dx$?

Comment: Yes (for the most part, anyway). Not sure why you'd want to write it like that though. You can turn it into an integration by having both x on one side.

Comment: i would write $$dy=xdx$$

Comment: I understand that dy=xdx is valid, but I'm just asking IF it is mathematically incorrect (or invalid) to write dy/x = dx

Comment: It is correct, but it unusable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but why would you want to?

With $\frac{dy}{dx}=x$ you can just integrate with respect to x to get $y=\frac{x^2}{2}+C.$

(if you want to be completionist then $\frac{dy}{dx}=x$ turns into $dy=x\ dx$)